# What is the deposit amount when creating liquidity pool?

Tags: uniswap

I am trying to create a test liquidity pool using mock token on Uniswap. I've been trying to find out how is this deposit amount calculated and what does it exactly mean? Doesn't matter what is the starting price or price ranges, whatever I do this is always base $15. Can someone could explain this a little to me?

[image]

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Comment: no, not really ..